# Integrated barcode scanner in App Inventor

Tags: android, integration, barcode, barcode-scanner, app-inventor

I am creating an app that is scanning a barcode and exporting the results to a spreadsheet online. But I would like to know how I can integrate the scanner into the app using App Inventor as currently my app is opening the Zxing application to scan the barcode but I want it to scan within the app or even have it running in the background once on the scanning page.

[These are my current coding block which allow the scanner to open externally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVf9J.png)
[image]

Could someone advice me on how I can get it to be integrated into the app itself without the user having to install Zxing or any other additional scanning application.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation of the Barcode Scanner](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/sensors.html#BarcodeScanner) and set the property `UseExternalScanner` to false

> **UseExternalScanner**
>   If true App Inventor will look for and use an external scanning program such as "Bar Code Scanner."

Comment: After i set this to false what scanner is it using to run the scan and would this scan be something that runs in the background of the app.